# Tracking registry changes from VS2010 build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, com, registry, cruisecontrol.net

I have a problem with our build system in that it registers all COM interfaces for our files in the registry for every build as a different CLSID. I suspect that this is due to the policy adopted by my company to change the build version for all files regardless if the source code was modified or not.

Consequently over time the build system grows very slow due to inherited registry bloat.

Is there an easy way to track changes made by the previous build and clean up the registry for all CLSID values earlier than the current version?

A better solution would be to make it so that all COM interfaces use the same GUID for their CLSID from build to build. This would cause the current entries to continue to be overwritten by the previous entries. However, I am not certain if this is possible.

Comment: I presume this question is related to your previous question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853141/cruisecontrol-build-times-degrade-on-vmware-workstation/23480558#23480558

Comment: Short answer, no. This issue appears to relate to the way that your build process updates your version numbers? If so, does the issue persist if you remove the version updating?

Comment: That's possibly the biggest possible mistake you could make for a COM server.  Hardcoding  the guids by using the [Guid] attribute would be the next biggest mistake you could make.

Comment: Are you com-registering by name?  Can't you just un(com)register the com object (with some exec task ignore-any-errors).... before registering?

Comment: I agree that hardcoding GUIDs is bad business. I was just wondering if it were possible to use the obj file from a previous build as a 'reference' for the current build so that it would utilize the same GUID for the rebuild. I will have to test to see if building visual studio a second time (without changing the version) adds new entries to the registry. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @SimonLaing You are correct, the reason Wise Studio takes so long to build is that it is reading the registry during the build process. The larger the registry the more time it takes to build. ProcMon shows the constant read from registry, write to file process.